# DocumentOpen Word event is not working and how can I run the timer when the word file is opened

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins, word-addins

When the file is opened, I upload it to the server but when the file is opened Application_DocumentOpen method doesn't work

How can I run my upload method every 30 seconds when the file is opened

```html
  void Application_DocumentOpen(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc)
 {
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);
            timer.Enabled = true;
            
            
            timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => 
            DocumentEditingSendToServer(Doc.Application.ActiveDocument);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a timer_tick method and do your upload from that method every 30 seconds.

Like this:

```
Timer Timer1 = new Timer();

void Application_DocumentOpen(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc)
 {
            InitializeTimer();
}

void InitializeTimer()
{
     Timer1.Interval = 30000;
     Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer1_Tick);
}

private void Timer1_Tick (Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DocumentEditingSendToServer(Doc.Application.ActiveDocument);
}
```